# How to catch back and home button in jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have tried the majority of the solutions posted both here and on other sites. I still can't catch the back button on my PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile android app. Let's start with the basic one:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
function backKeyDown() {
    alert('back button pressed');
}
```

That doesn't seem to be firing at all.

Another thing I want to do is catch when the home button is pressed. I want to make it so that the app gets killed when I press the home button, mainly for security purposes.

Can anybody help me with my above dilemma?

Comment: Try including the `org.apache.cordova.App` and `org.apache.cordova.App` plugins to the `config.xml` file. I can remember that it didn't work for me once and I included those plugins (I'm not sure which one did the trick) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue. I haven't fully solved it yet, but the problem seems to be that calls to the app plugin, including the call to enable button events, aren't running.

I was able to get the backbutton event firing by enabling the native part of the event binding in the java code:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/loading.html", 20000);
appView.bindButton(true);
```

Update:

I found the actual cause of the problem - a bug in the development version of cordova that is now fixed.

Usually updating cordova is the first thing I try, but a simple pull didn't work because the repo is now http://github.com/apache/cordova-android - the old incubator-cordova-android still exists, but is not being updated and contains a version of the code from before this bug was fixed.